# Need to load http js and css over https - getting mix_content error

Tags: php, proxy, file-get-contents

I am trying to load an http website in an iframe in a https website. I know it will give me mixed_content error for js and css, so to resolve the mixed_content I am using proxy like below :

```
$url = "http://www.myweb.com";
$PROXY_HOST = "47.52.24.117"; // Proxy server address
$PROXY_PORT = "80";    // Proxy server port
$PROXY_USER = "";    // Username
$PROXY_PASS = "";   // Password
// Username and Password are required only if your proxy server needs basic authentication

$auth = base64_encode("$PROXY_USER:$PROXY_PASS");
stream_context_set_default(
 array(
  'http' => array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'proxy' => "tcp://$PROXY_HOST:$PROXY_PORT",
    'request_fulluri' => true,
    'header' => "Proxy-Authorization: Basic $auth"
   // Remove the 'header' option if proxy authentication is not required
  )
 )
);
$res = file_get_contents($url);
echo $res;
```

But I am still getting mixed_content error for js and css. (Images and html content are loading fine under https).

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly comment - but space in the comment box is limited here.

First, you didn't mention what browser you are using. MSIE can throw this error for several things which are not mixed content. If you are using MSIE you might try using a different browser and see if it the problem is one of Microsoft's quirks or if the fault really is in your code.

When you say "like below" I hope this is not the code you are using to retrieve content from the remote site as you have hard coded the URL here. I'll that this is being handled via a front-controller, mod_rewrite or a 404 handler which you've not told us about, that you have verified that the URLs are being translated correctly by the proxy script / that the content being supplied is what you expect and cleared your cache between tests....

Have you checked that the scripts and CSS you are downloading do not contain URLs pointing back to http:// URLs?

There is a further issue with the code you've shown us in that it does not check / pass on the mimetype.

Comment: I am using Chrome and Firefox browser. For testing purpose i have put hard coded url here otherwise the urls loaded dynamic in website. I also clear browser cache and test in private browser too. I also tried with add mimetype. The js, css and img all have http:// urls but js and css are showing mixed_content error in developer tool firebug.